# Why does XQuery return the divisor instead of the division result?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have the following XML document:

```
<releases>
  <release>
    <videos>
      <video duration="599" embed="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TivSU1-ASPQ"/>
    </videos>
  </release>
</releases>
```

I would like to convert the `@duration` to minutes and seconds. I am using the following code to convert

```
declare namespace local = "http://www.foobar.org";
declare function local:convert($v) as xs:decimal?
{
  $v/60
};

let $r := doc("releases.xml") return
for $i in $r/releases/release/videos/video
return local:convert($i/@duration)
```

However, I am getting a `60` as the result. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

PS: Please note that I have multiple videos, that is why I am using a FLWOR expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XQuery, `/` does not denote the division operator, but an axis step. Use `div` instead. Your query returns the decimal `60` for each `$v`. You can also try `(<foo/>, <bar/>)/42` for a similar result, which will return the number 42 twice.

Additionally, that function will fail for incompatible types. The result of a division is an `xs:double`, not an `xs:decimal` (which is only for integers). Declare the function as returning `xs:double` instead (or [cast/round to a decimal](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0011.html#c0059), if you want integers).

```
declare function local:convert($v) as xs:double?
{
  $v div 60
};
```